# Validate only visible fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am validating one form. when required fields are not entered it will return `alert`.its working fine.

Now I have hide some form fields by adding **`ng-class`**,when I click submit I don't want to validate hidden fields I want to validate only those fields which are not having `hidden class`.

These are my inputs:

```
    <section  ng-class="{'hidden':true}">
            <input class="required" ng-model="currentData.name" />      
    </section>
    <section ng-class="{'hidden':true}">
            <input  class="required" ng-model="currentData.id"/>    
    </section>
    <section>
        <input class="required" type="text" ng-model='currentData.age'/>    
    </section>

    <section ng-class="{'hidden':true}">
        <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.gender'/> 
    </section>

    <section>
        <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.description'/>    
    </section>


Here am validating my fields :

    $form.find('input.required').each(function() {

                var $this = $(this)
                if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
                    alert("enter required fields")
                }       
            })

I have added `:visible`  its working good.But that wont be a proper solution I guess.Because if there are multiple tabs which is not having `hidden class`means, it will validate only current tab user currently viewing.

    $form.find('input.required:visible').each(function() {

                var $this = $(this)
                if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
                    alert("enter required fields")
                }       
            })
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You should use angular form validations instead of validating with jquery. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for more info

Comment: use type="hidden" in those fields which are meant to be hidden instead of adding a class.

Comment: Guys I tried like this `$form.find('input.required').parents('section').not(".hidden").each(function() {` still am getting `required field missing`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').find('input.required').parent('*:not(".hidden")').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this)
        if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
            alert("enter required fields")
        }
    })
```

assuming `$('form')` is `<form></form>`,

otherwise it should be something like
`$('#form')` for `<div id="form"></div>`

Comment: If I have more than one parent for `input` ,but I have `hidden` class is for super parent .Then how can I mention?

Comment: I have 2 parents for input 
 and my first parent is `section`,I added `hidden` class for section only,is this structure correct? `$form.find('input.required').closest('section:not(".hidden")').each(function() {`

Comment: This depends of your version of jQuery but should work in most cases.

`parent()` only reference the direct parent, if you want to select a top level parent you would use `parents()`

You can reference the container of `<section>`, like

    `<div id="sectionContainer">
       <section ng-class="...">`

Then you do something like

`$('form').find('input.required').parent('#sectionContainer section:not(".hidden")')`


Note: if the `:not(".hidden")` is causing you trouble, you can use the jQuery equivalent which is `.not('.classnamehere')`

Comment: still am getting required fields missing :( :(

Comment: I saw in your other comment you are doing
`$form.find('input.required')`

why not just `$('form section:not(".hidden")')` ?

Comment: No I cant do like this.Because some elements may not have section parent.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution:

```
$form.find('section').not(".hidden").closest('input.required').each(function() {})
```

I just changed my elements order.